# Confirmation Action - Confirmation text, computed value not dynamic?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

on my xpage I have a button where I have made the confirmation text computed with SSJS:

```
<xp:button value="Queue" id="btnQueue"
                            styleClass="btn-primary">

                        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
                            <xp:this.action>
                                <xp:confirm>
                                    <xp:this.message><![CDATA[#{javascript:return "Are you sure you want to change value from " + getComponent("From").value + " to " + getComponent("To").value + "?";}]]></xp:this.message>
                                </xp:confirm>
                            </xp:this.action></xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
```

I am using the same components to calculate the disable property. This works fine. Why not the computed text property?

Answer (score 1):

Remember SSJS runs on the server, CSJS on the browser. `#{javascript:....}` means everything is being generated server-side and a literal message to the user is being passed to the browser, which will then be generated when the user clicks the button. So the "from" and "to" values are those that were on the server when it was last passed to the browser.

Don't use the simple action (which passes a server-side message to the browser). Use CSJS instead, `confirm('My Message');`. To get variable content from the current browser page into it, you need CSJS to retrieve the value from the relevant HTML element on the page, based on the ID. To use that, pass `#{id:From}` and `#{id:To}` into your preferred CSJS method for retrieving an element by ID.

Comment: ok I will try your approach. but in DDE it says:write a javascript expression to compute the value. then I can select javascript (server side) so I am in the assumption I can make the message computed. also in the code it says <xp:confirm>
          <xp:this.message><![CDATA[#{javascript:return "Are you sure you want to change from " + getComponent("From").value + " to " + getComponent("To").value + "?";}]]></xp:this.message>
         </xp:confirm>

Comment: how do I combine this csjs with the other ssjs code? e.g. I have now confirm("Are you sure you want to change from " + XSP.getElementById("#{id:From}").value +" to " + XSP.getElementById("#{id:To}").value + "?"). But when I select the cancel button the SSJS will run anyway. :-?

Comment: As you may have worked out, on the Client tab you can click Script Editor to enter CSJS. If that returns true, the SSJS continues. If it returns false, it cancels. So if you do `return confirm....` it will stop if you select cancel.